# Height of the Status bar in android emulator is very tall

Tags: android, statusbar, android-statusbar

The height of the status bar is very big, I thought is a bug in my app. But if I open up the other default apps like message or any app it keeps the same height. Is there any work around to fix this issue?

I thought it would work fine if i run in real device. But while I connect the phone and run directly, it is also happening in my device also.

I tried in Android Emulator 9.0.

[Android Emulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYnrh.png)

Comment: You're saying it happens in every app on emulator then you say it happens in your app on real device. Where is the issue? Emulator or your app?

Comment: @Pawel the issue exists on both real device and emulator. In emulator, it has the same issue for other apps as well like message,call, any inbuilt app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researched for some time, found that it was issue with emulator and need to restart the device and emulator. then still it was showing wrongly in emulator, but in device it shown perfectly.

Restarting the device was helpful.